# AddTransient UserManager being disposed of when calling from same controller 2nd time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Asp.Net Core WebApi with a controller which has 2x services injected into the constructor.

In turn they have my `DbContext` and `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` injected into them.

The endpoint in question creates a user and then creates a password reset token for the user to set the password (this is mailed out to the user).

For separation of concerns I have the following code in my controller;

```
//create the user
var response = await _signUpService.CreateNewUser(model);

//create the reset token
var token = await _userService.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(response.Id);
```

The methods for each are as follows, firstly in the SignUpService;

```
 private readonly Func<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> _userManagerFactory;

 public async Task<ApplicationUser> CreateNewUser(UserModel model)
    {
        Func<Task<ApplicationUser>> func = async () => 
        {
            using (var context = _contextFactory())
            using (var userManager = _userManagerFactory())
            { 
                /*removed for brevity*/
                return context.Save(model);
            }
        };

        return await this.ExecuteAsync(func);

    }
```

and then in UserService;

```
private readonly Func<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> _userManagerFactory;

public async Task<string> GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(int userId)
{

        Func<Task<string>> func = async () =>
        {
            using (var context = _userManagerFactory())
            {
                var user = await context.FindByIdAsync(userId.ToString());

                var token = await context.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

                return token;
            }
        };

        return await this.ExecuteAsync(func);
}
```

I add the dependency inject as follows;

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDataContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();    

services.AddTransient<Func<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>(provider => () => provider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>());
```

However, on the second using, i.e. `using (var context = _userManagerFactory())` I get the following error thrown;

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'UserStore`9'.

Now I can access my `DbContext` on a second call but not the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`?

As far as I am aware the instance of the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` (and so `UserStore` as well??) should be added per service? Bu this doesn't seem to be the case?

**UPDATE**

I have tried altering the following to specify the deendency injection in the WebApi `Startup`.

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDataContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddTransient<UserStore>();
        services.AddTransient <UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddTransient<Func<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>(provider => () => provider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>());
```

but this too is throwing the same error.

Comment: My first guess is that your _userManagerFactor that you're trying to use in the using block doesn't implement IDisposable. Would it be possible to remove the second using statement?

Comment: I cant remove the using statements as I need to access the `UserManager` in each of the methods. It seems to be disposing of the `UserStore` after the first call on CreateNewUser. I assume I need something like `AddTransient<IUserStore, DefaultImplementationUserStore>();` so it knows to inject a new Transient?

Comment: The transient will create a new instance every time you getService from the service provider.A single instance is enough in your case, so my recommendation is for you to use the "AddSingleton", when adding the add singleton or other, the correct implementation is the interface and concrete implementation of that interface. When using transient is imperative to implement IDisposable otherwise you may have problems with the GC.

Comment: It seems like the same instance of UserManager is being injected into each service used by your controller via Func<UserManager<>>. In CreateNewUser you dispose of it, then attempting to use the same, disposed, instance in GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync throws the exception. Remove the 'using' statement from CreateNewUser and instead let the lifetime of injected dependencies be controlled through the services collection. Maybe also consider injecting UserManager<> rather than a Func<>.

Comment: To maintain my SOLID structure I would prefer not to change the dispose at the end of the Service method call. However, I am just wondering why it is not creating a `Transient` for each service? As it appears to do with my standard `DbContext` which works in a similar way and has an instance per service